# CSS Content auto and footer/header stuck

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm creating a webpage with CSS. Now i want to have the header (64mm) on top of the page and the footer (25mm) at the bottom of the page. 
The content must have a auto height between the header and the footer. So the height of the content depends on the heigth of the screen.
When I use "position: absolute" and "bottom: 0" for the footer, the content goes under the footer.

How is it possible to make the content end at the footer and make a scrollbar in the content?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as an FYI: using `position:absolute` removes the element in question from the normal document flow. It no longer reserves space for itself, which is why you see it appear over your content section. See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position for a better explanation.